# trying to install libncurses dev package for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, ncurses

I am trying to install `libncurses` for Ubuntu 14.04. But, it is showing the following error:

```
root@sharwariDell:/usr/src# sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: The [package should exist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libncurses5-dev). Check your /etc/apt/sources.list is correct, then do `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Answer (score 10):

The package `libncurses5-dev` is available on [base:main repository for Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/libncurses5-dev).

So, make sure you have enable main & universe repositories:

> The **main** component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The **universe** component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

[image]

If you choose **command-line**, following command may help you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

If you face any **unmet-dependencies** then refer [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/256099)